# DNS setting up an incoming A record

Tags: domain-name-system

An external location has an external DNS that needs to connect to our server to access a website from on our server. Their client email and DNS are all not on our server.

Our server hosts their website **only**. Our server **does** have it's own DNS and email systems, as well as a fully working testing (sub)domain of the local website (`develop.website.com` - a sub-domain of another domain).

Their remote DNS address is `domaink.net`.
Our approach has been to set up a DNS record on our server with their domain name:

```
domaink.net.     86400     NS     ns1.server.co.uk
domaink.net.     86400     NS     ns2.server.co.uk
domaink.net.     14400     A    123.456.678.789 (our server IP)
www.domaink.net.     14400     CNAME     domaink.net
```

And Have them put an A record on their DNS:

```
domaink.net.    14400   A    123.456.678.789  (our server IP)
```

They have updated their DNS to point the A record to our server IP, but that URL is not connecting.

What am I missing?

Is my understanding of DNS delegation correct?

Should they in fact have a DNS that delegates their website A record to our testing website that's already set up?

```
domaink.net.    14400   A    develop.website.com
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your DNS is irrelevant; there is nothing off your server that says people should be looking at it. Presumably, their registrar points to their nameservers that are off site. To test that you would `nslookup -type=soa domaink.net`, and that will tell you who actually is authoritative for their domain. You would then add the A and CNAME records `domaink.net A 123.456.678.789` and `www.domaink.net. CNAME domaink.net.` to those authoritative nameservers.

Comment: Ok this does make sense. However, on our own server, surely there needs to be some sort of DNS so that incoming web browsers guided to our server by the client / remote DNS `domaink.net.    14400   A    123.456.678.789` ? I checked the authoritative nameservers  as suggested and they're their google DNS as expected.

Comment: Actually, your local DNS is only used on those machines that specifically are told to look at it, if your web server is behind an external firewall then you can set that DNS entry in your firewall's DNS forwarder so your local machines can refer to the site by name, if your machine is sitting solo it's enough to set that name in `/etc/hosts` (assuming Linux). If you do have a firewall, remember that you also have to create a pinhole through it so that incoming port 80 and 443 requests are accepted and directed to your web server.

Comment: Thanks. The server is linux and uses CSF firewall, we usually have DNS internal on the server (server hosts DNS and websites all on the same space) so I'm unfamiliar with if we need to update any of these thirdparty hosts and similar. But I think that's something I can look at once I'm sure that the client's 3rd Party DNS is correctly set up . cheers.

Comment: Basically DNS says, for the name, here's an IP address. When the request comes to your machine, it comes as IP only, there is a name (in the host header, used to determine which web site your web server should look at) but DNS's part of the job is done. Your web server does not use DNS to look up the site, it assumes that if the request comes in, it must be for one of the sites that it hosts.